# Using WCF Data Services 5.6.0 with Entity Framework 6+

Tags: .net, wcf, odata, entity-framework-6

I have been trying to get our WCF Data Service to work with the new Entity Framework 6.

I found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx) which explains a supposedly easy and painless way to fix this issue.

I followed the directions posted exactly. When I first install:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider -Version 1.0.0-alpha1 -Pre
```

I get the error:

> Error      16           The type
>   'Microsoft.OData.Service.DataService`1' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.OData.Service, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.     C:\Realtime Source\RTR
>   6.x\RTRServices\RTRWCFDataService\RTRWCFDataService\RTRWCFData.svc.cs                21           16           RTRWCFDataService

Upon researching that it seems that the solution is to upgrade to alpha 2... and to do this use the command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider -Pre
```

When I use this command the Package Manager Console spits out two errors:

> Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could
>   not load type
>   'System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand'
>   from assembly 'E ntityFramework.PowerShell, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'." At C:\Realtime
>   Source\RTR
>   6.x\RTRServices\RTRWCFDataService\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:698
>   char:31
>   +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException   Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load
>   type 'System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.AddProviderCommand'
>   from assembly 'EntityFramework .PowerShell, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'." At C:\Realtime
>   Source\RTR
>   6.x\RTRServices\RTRWCFDataService\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.1\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:698
>   char:31
>   +     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom <<<< (
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Then I lose the ability to access the `Microsoft.OData` namespace... basically keeping me from the class that I need to finish the upgrade `Microsoft.OData.Service.Providers.EntityFrameworkDataService`

Any help at all on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I was able to install the Alpha 2 release, I've run into quite a few issues with this provider.  Many of them yield unclear or misleading exceptions, as you can find in the comments of the original announcement.  And, currently, the developers aren't actively engaging the community in working through the issues.  In fact, given that nearly two months have passed since the last Alpha release, it's unclear whether or not this is a priority within Microsoft.

Given this, I wouldn't recommend basing any production code on this provider.  In fact, I'd be hesitant to even develop against it with the hope that a more stable version will release later until we've seen more momentum behind this version of the library.  My suspicion is that with the release of ASP.NET Web API 2.0, WCF Data Services has been put on the back burner.

Until then, you're probably better off pursuing one of the following options:

- Falling back to Entity Framework 5.0.
- Building a custom [Web API w/ OData extensions](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint).
- Adopting Microsoft's new [RESTier](https://github.com/OData/RESTier).
- Using an alternate service layer, such as [Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider)*.

This probably isn't the answer you're hoping for, nor does it address your immediate hurdle, but until there's more movement on the official provider I'd consider these options instead.

* Breeze is a client JavaScript library for consuming oData services, but it also includes a server-side library for interfacing with popular O/RMs, including Entity Framework 6.0 as well as NHibernate.

Comment: Why do I only find these posts when I've sunk a ton of work into something? I would have thought it would be common courtesy for the guys working on the 'alpha' to put up a statement indicating that they've put it aside and it's buggy as SH** so please don't use it... I've just run into the fact that you can't do more than one additional command (so filter with expand for example) without it ignoring all commands bar the first one... sigh back to EF5.0

Comment: FYI... WCF Data Services Entity Service Provider is now up to v1.0.0-beta2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/08/18/wcf-data-services-entity-framework-provider-is-updated-with-wcf-data-service-5-6-2.aspx

Comment: FYI: Microsoft now has another project, [RESTier](https://github.com/OData/RESTier), which provides very similar functionality as WCF Data Services, but does a better job of integrating seamlessly with ASP.NET Web API. 

For instance, to customize the functionality of a particular endpoint, a developer can simply create a controller and the routing will automatically use that instead of the OOTB RESTier controller. This provides the best of both worlds (IMHO) between the simplicity of WCF Data Services and the flexibility of ASP.NET Web API.

Answer (score 1):

About the issue you met when "Install-Package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider -Pre"

From the error info, it seems that EntityFramework.psm1 of version 6.0.0 is trying to load some code from EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll, Version=5.0.0.0. I tried on my solution, I cannot repro this issue.

So my guess is that you mixed EntityFramework 5.0.0 and EntityFramework 6.0.1 somehow, but actually I don't know how. So my suggestion is to do following steps:

1. uninstall-package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider
2. uninstall-package EntityFramework
3. uninstall-package EntityFramework -version 5.0.0
4. Then reinstall "Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider" package by "Install-Package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider -Pre"

If the first three steps cannot be finished correctly on your project, just manually delete all the EntityFramework folders and Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider.1.0.0-alpha2 folder in packages. And then do the fourth step

Hope it works for you