# Setting up EntityFramework 6 and WCF Data Services 5.6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to setup a project for Entityframwork 6 and WCF Data Services 5.6. I went through [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx)

I installed NuGet package By:

> Install-Package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider -Pre

After That I tried to ADO.Net Entity Data Model using Wizard. 
It doesn't allow me to Go futher. Error is like this

> Your Project references the latest version of E F; However and EF database provider comapatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. Exit this wizard, install ta compatible provider, and rebuild your project before performing this action.
>   and a link :
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj730568

My database is Oracle 11g and I'm using DevArt whose version is Oracle pro 8.0.146.0

I thought it is some issue with DotConnect I checked with vendor they gave me [this link](http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html#ProviderRegistration)

I followed this too. But no success.

When I try adding DevArt Data Model *edml it gives me Ef 6 too.
so  when Create this edml and try a WCF Data Service give me  The exception message is:

> The property 'EntityState' on type 'Models.USER' is not a valid property. Make sure that the type of the property is a public type and a supported primitive type or a entity type with a valid key or a complex type.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: at System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.BuildTypeProperties

How can I set these up together?

Comment: I did my best to try to edit this post, but I dont believe that you have put in the errors exactly as received.  Over all, this is very unclear.

Comment: When I install EF 6 by NuGet Package Manager, Why I'm not able to User ADO.Net Data Model Wizard? I'm unable to attach Image Here Sorry

Comment: Problem 2: When I use DevArt Data Model Wizard I'm able to create *edml file but When I create the service I get error.
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The property 'EntityState' on type 'Models.USER' is not a valid property. Make sure that the type of the property is a public type and a supported primitive type or a entity type with a valid key or a complex type.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: 
at System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.BuildTypeProperties

Comment: I edited your title, post and tags to more accurately reflect that you are using WCF **Data Services**, which is related to but not WCF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Entityframework 6 , WCF Data Service 5.6 , DevArt oracle Connector**

Now Let me Ans for my questions itself.

1. Entityframework 6 & WCF Data Serice was not working from Day 1.  Why complex dependencies of EF 6 & Data Services 5.6.
2. DevArt Entity Wizard Create the Entities Data model with EntityObject which I don't why still why doesn't work with DataService.

So I followed Below mentioned Links like Final words
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx?Redirected=true

1. created a fresh Blank MVC Project for DataService 5.6
2. Install EF 6 with NuGet Package manager.
3. installed Install-Package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider -Version 1.0.0-alpha2
4. Create DataModel with DevArt EntityWizad for EF 6 choose DbContext Template (Don't why it still write the code with Both ObjectContext , DbContext
5. Remove Manually ObjectContext Auto Generated Code.
6. Add WCF data Service 5.6 For wizard
7. Change DataService  to EntityFrameworkDataService
8. Register Entity Provider 
   http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html

   believe me complex dependecy of dll is the hurdle to cross.
   For more you please read below threads. (Oopps.. I've not Reputation here so I can't post more links. Sorry)

Comment: Don't forget to use latest DevArt Connector I use 8.4.181.4

Comment: Refrences :http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4734171-retrieve-dbcontext-in-entityframeworkdataservice

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b7e6016-0631-4534-94bf-1e397b8fe1e1/cannot-upgrade-to-561-microsoftodataentityframeworkprovider?forum=adodotnetdataservices

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156205/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6

Comment: refrences 2: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59aba0c8-25bc-4c67-b1c8-f2086fe94dfa/56ef6actions-broken?forum=adodotnetdataservices


http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ea24952a-1039-4c27-9199-c54add1eda2c/is-microsoft-halting-development-on-wcf-data-services?forum=adodotnetdataservices

Answer (score 0):

> ... "Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. Exit this wizard, install a compatible driver, and rebuild your project before  performing this action"...

When working with EDM Designer you should add the registration of EF-provider to *.config before adding a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project. The sample for dotConnect for Oracle is available here: http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html

Entity Developer adds this registration of EF-provider to *.config automatically. We recommend you to use Entity Developer (Devart Entity Model, *.edml) instead of EDM Designer (ADO.NET Entity Data Model, *.edmx) because it is adjusted for working with Oracle and has an advanced functionality: http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/ed-vs-edm.html.

> ...The exception message is 'The property 'EntityState' on type 'Models.USER' is not a valid property. Make sure that the type of the property  is a public type and a supported primitive type or a entity type with a valid key or a complex type.'...

Please send us (support at devart*com) a small test project, with which the error could be reproduced, so that we are able to investigate it in more details and find a solution for you.